# Credit Card data capturing and verfication

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a website for a client of ours who want their customers to be able to book appointments on their new wordpress site that we are creating. The problem is that they want to capture the customer's credit card details so that they can charge the card a fee if they do not turn up.

I have been looking into this for some time now with no luck. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can capture this data without charging the customer immediately.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: good luck with that. if you need to ask how to capture CC details and store them (which then brings the PCI hammer down on your head), you probably shouldn't be attempting it in the first place.

Comment: I never want to visit your website if you store my card details. You can tell this to your client!

Comment: As mentioned you don't want to do that, because of all legal problems behind it. Just use a payment gateway from a third party provider.

Comment: http://www.brainsins.com/en/blog/top-10-payment-gateways-e-commerce-us/3661

Comment: Is there anyway to use a payment gateway, which would store the card details but only charge them if the admin okays it? otherwise the details would then be deleted after so long?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that they want to capture the customer's credit card
>   details so that they can charge the card a fee if they do not turn up.

Storing CC account info is simply illegal, *unless* you conform to very strict federal and state laws for storing such data.

Besides, there is no reason for you to write your own payment gateway and conform to security requirements for your site and your server. Google "payment gateway" and read.

You'll find different payment processors for CC's and purchase orders, ways to bill through a web interface at those processors, plugins for WordPress, and plugins that allow for automatic/reoccurring billing, etc.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Do you have any advice on what plugins I can use to access the payment gateway and therefore allow the client to access the gateway to charge the card in the case where the customer does not show up.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic on SO. If you do your own research, you'll learn enough to find that what you want to do is complex and needs to be secure; you may be better off simply hiring someone on a freelancing site such as Upwork or Guru.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the most well understood use of a payment gateway / payment API is making an immediate charge, many allow exactly this kind of use.

[Stripe](https://stripe.com) does it by decoupling [customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers) and [tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/api#tokens) from [charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges) - allowing you to create a token (represents the customer's card data) that you can charge later if needed.

[PayPal](https://paypal.com) calls it a [vault](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card) where you can store card details and later use it when [creating a payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment).

Answer (score 0):

Most payment gateways allow you to securely store payment information via their API.  Planetauthorize (http://planetauthorize.net/addons/customervault.html) calls it Customer Vault and Authorize.net (http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim) calls it CIM.  There are many others.